# How to force word wrap in reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that renders out text, sometimes that text is a long string of characters and when I export to word the columns that are generated are stretched out. I need to force a word wrap of the text even if it breaks a word (long string of text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Reporting Services doesn't control this behavior in Word and thus is unable to expose a way for you to do so.  Your best bet here would be to wrap your string/field in an expression that manually injects breaking characters.  Using specific knowledge about your report in question (i,e. width of textbox, size of font, type of font, etc,) you can get pretty close to, if not exactly to, your desired behavior.

Comment: unfortunately the long string of text is not isolated (it is within a paragraph, coming from a TEXT field in sql server), so I would have to do some parsing to manually break the text.